# Разработка интерфейса для управления модулями

Tags: qt, интерфейс

Необходимо разработать программу посредством QT, в которой будет возможность добавлять разные модули (возможно на других языках). Суть в том, что нужно каким то образом организовать каталог, в который можно будет добавлять новые программы, и они должны отображаться в окне этого интерфейса с возможностью их запуска. Можно было бы сделать эти модули "вшитыми", но тогда пришлось бы постоянно переписывать исходный код, и это было бы неудобно. Может быть есть какие нибудь методы решения данной задачи?

Comment: Навскидку можно завести папку, куда складывать файлик (или файлики) в котором будет храниться метаинформация по "модулю" - название там, иконка, путь к исполняемому файлу, еще что-то. Файлик читать при старте интерфейса и формировать каталог

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qt-tools-plugandpaint-example.html

Comment: Благодарю, поизучаю информацию